# row wise iteration with purrr does not work as expected

Tags: r, iteration, purrr

I usually use for loops to iterate over objects. I recently stumbled over a function called [`pmap()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html) from the `purrr` package, which provides a alternative way of mapping over an object in parallel.

My example below does not work, and I don't understand why. Does anybody have an idea, why the output list `result` does not get updated when iterating over a dataframe? A for loop would produce the desired output, but at the cost of readability.

```r
# load packages
library(tidyverse)

# create small dataset
dat <- mtcars[1:3, 1:3] %>% 
  rownames_to_column()

# view dat
dat
#>         rowname  mpg cyl disp
#> 1     Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160
#> 2 Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160
#> 3    Datsun 710 22.8   4  108

# prepare output list
result <- list()

# map over dat and update object result
pwalk(dat, function(rowname, mpg, cyl, disp) {
  result[[rowname]] <- paste(mpg, cyl, disp)
})

# result did not get updated
result
#> list()
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: You are passing a function to pwalk and modifying a variable inside that function. Variables you modify inside functions to not live outside of functions.

Comment: Something like this might be a better tidyverse alternative. `set_names(pmap(dat %>% select(-rowname), paste), dat$rowname)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @MrFlick you are trying to assign a value to `result` inside a function, which has its own environment.

You can use the `<<-` assignment operator to modify `result` in the global environment (outside the function) and barely change your code. But be cautions when using it, as to not modify variables (or even functions) you did not intend to.

From the R documentation (`` ?`<<-` ``)

> The operators <<- and ->> are normally only used in functions, and cause a search to be made through parent environments for an existing definition of the variable being assigned. If such a variable is found (and its binding is not locked) then its value is redefined, otherwise assignment takes place in the global environment.

```r
result <- list() # Defined in the global environment

pwalk(dat, function(rowname, mpg, cyl, disp) {
  result[[rowname]] <<- paste(mpg, cyl, disp)
  })

result

# Output
$`Mazda RX4`
[1] "21 6 160"

$`Mazda RX4 Wag`
[1] "21 6 160"

$`Datsun 710`
[1] "22.8 4 108"
})
```

Comment: Good addition. But using `<<-` to modify variables in the global environment is, generally speaking, a very bad practice.

Comment: I agree. For 99% of the cases it is really not recommended. And your solution (returning a list from `pmap` and assigning it to `result`) is the best practice. But it never hurts to know some "tricks".

Comment: Agreed.`<<-` is useful in some circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

As @MrFlick mentioned, you are modifying variables in the function environment. This is why you don't see the expected result.

You can try:

```
# map over dat and update object result
result <- pmap(dat, function(rowname, mpg, cyl, disp) {
  paste(mpg, cyl, disp)
})

names(result) <- dat$rowname
```

or

```
result <- apply(dat, 1, function(x){
  paste(x[2],x[3],x[4])
})

names(result) <- dat$rowname
```

in base R.